# How to generate struct with ProtoGen from proto file

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

We've been using protobuf-net ProtoGen to generate C# .cs file from *.proto file. We would like instead of class to generate struct. e.g.

```
[DataContract]
public struct Entity1
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public double Field1 { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to extract protocol buffer using method `Serializer.GetProto` for class and struct type. It seems, that protocol buffer (.proto) doesn't recognize difference between the struct and class. So I imply, that could be a parameter in ProtoGen to choose between class/struct for generation from .proto. Does the feature exist or how could I solve generation of the struct from *.proto?

Comment: Why do you specifically need a `struct` though?

Comment: @ Lloyd
In .NET, a struct does not carry the additional runtime and memory overhead compared to a class. For example, consider the definition of a 3D vector in SharpDX. It's declared as a structure containing 3 fields and not as a class. Part of the reason is because you want a list of Vectors to be blittable, but another reason is that allocating huge (say one million items) array of vectors incurs an incredible memory overhead if a vector is declared as a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the current time, ProtoGen only emits classes; since the data is inherently mutable, I would say that this is reasonable, but - two options present themselves:

- edit `csharp.xslt` to replace `class` with `struct` (or *copy* `csharp.xslt`, and use the `-t` parameter to tell it to use the copy)
- use it "as is", and make judicious use of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> (low-tech, I know; but it will work)

Comment: Is this still supposed to work on the latest github source? Trying it but I hit `throw new NotSupportedException("IExtensible is not supported in structs or classes with inheritance");`

Comment: Ok, never mind. Removing IExtensible on struct types seems to work fine. I've decided to hand write the C# code rather than use protogen as I can use public fields and structs instead of properties etc.