# Protobuf-net with oneof in .proto file

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am using the ProtoGen tool (version 1.0.0.280) from protobuf-net to generate a `.cs` file from a `.proto` file.

However, using the `oneof` keyword results in the error:

```
test.proto:13:3: Expected "required", "optional", or "repeated".
test.proto:13:25: Missing field number.
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358233/how-to-generate-struct-with-protogen-from-proto-file) mentions that `oneof` is a new feature and may not be universally supported.

I think I have the latest ProtoGen version, but is there a newer (beta?) version which supports this functionality, or is one planned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this feature is not yet supported.

Multiple feature requests are listed in Protobuf-net Github Issues, as issues [#47](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues/47) and [#54](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues/54).